# Allowing nulls to be passed through tryCatch

Tags: r, try-catch

I have a simple function that checks whether two supplied arguments are characters, and if not, throws an error

```
check_args_are_chr <- function(arg1, arg2){
  tryCatch({
    stopifnot(is.character(arg1), is.character(arg2))},
    error = function(e) stop("Arguments must be supplied as characters"))

}

check_args_are_chr("one", 2)
> Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Arguments must be supplied as characters
```

However, arg2 is an optional argument which isn't always passed into the function. NULL is also an acceptable value

I wanted to incorporate it so the expr passed to `stopifnot` was

`is.character(arg2) && is.null(arg2)`

```
check_args_are_chr <- function(arg1, arg2){
  tryCatch({
    stopifnot(is.character(arg1), is.character(arg2) && is.null(arg2))},
    error = function(e) stop("Arguments must be supplied as characters"))

}
```

But this still makes the tryCatch throw an exception. How can I modify this so that acceptable classes are `character` or `NULL`

Comment: Simple: you cannot have *both* `is.character` and `is.null` return `TRUE`. Use logical `||`, not `&&`.

Comment: Ugh, not sure why I couldn't see that. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your code doesn't work as expected because you are confusing (binary) **or** `||` with **and** `&&`

Second, using tryCatch this way doesn't really make sense imho. Just do `if (...) stop("Arguments must be supplied as characters")`. On the downside the `if` statement is more awkward this way, but less awkward than using `tryCatch`.

Comment: Yes, in this context `tryCatch` doesn't make much sense. It's because I'm trimming down to a minimal example. The full function contains more code that makes `tryCatch` more useful, but I just wanted to make sure I got an answer that works with the functions context

Answer (score 0):

Either use `missing` to check whether `arg2` was given:

```
 (missing(arg2) || (is.null(arg2) || is.character(arg2)))
```

or set a default value `arg2 = NULL`